# Display problems in Chrome and Brave in 20.04 since a few weeks back

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, google-chrome

I had zero problems with my 20.04 installation until a few weeks back when Chrome and Brave suddenly started to behave strangely, graphics-wise:

- large, rectangular areas go black
- large, rectangular areas keep showing what was on the screen before I switched windows,
- font rendition errors on some sites, e.g. Youtube,
- display not updated on resize (ctrl +, ctrl -) but just rendered on top of the old view
- when viewing autoplaying videos on reddit, everything else in the viewport is blanked out, until the video is scrolled away.

Examples:

[image]

[image]

Driver info:

```
$ modinfo -F filename `lshw -c video | awk '/configuration: driver/{print $2}' | cut -d= -f2`
/lib/modules/5.4.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko
/lib/modules/5.4.0-45-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko
```

So I have those two driver files. When were they last updated?

```
$ ll /lib/modules/5.4.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3267193 aug 26 15:15 /lib/modules/5.4.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko
$ ll /lib/modules/5.4.0-45-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 27792698 sep  3 07:38 /lib/modules/5.4.0-45-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko
```

So, respectively, 3 and 12 days ago, which fits my experience.

So what do I do now?

- Wait and see if the next (when?) update fixes things?
- Manually install (how?) the last driver known to work?

This is not a problem in Firefox, but I need Chrome and Brave to work.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with Chrome 85 and the underlying Chromium engine. I can reproduce this 100% after suspend/wake. I'm using Nividia native drivers, tried both 440 and 450. Verified it's Chromium issue by rolling back to Chrome 84 -- no more glitches.